# Can someone explain this? [C++]

Tags: c++

From C++ Primer:

> The next statement
>
> ```
> std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
> ```
>
> reads the input. The input operator (the » operator) behaves
>   analogously to the output operator. It takes an istream as its
>   left-hand operand and an object as its right-hand operand. It reads
>   data from the given istream and stores what was read in the given
>   object. Like the output operator, the input operator returns its
>   left-hand operand as its result.  Hence, this expression is equivalent
>   to
>
> ```
> (std::cin >> v1) >> v2;
> ```

I don't get it. How are the two expressions equivalent? Maybe it's simple. But I don't get it.

Comment: Have you tried actually running it?

Comment: `a+b+c` is equivalent to `(a+b)+c`. The "magic" is that the operator >> returns its first operand, the stream.

Comment: Legrojan, no. I read a whole section, and then check out stuff by running that stuff and then make stuff too. I haven't tried this yet. I'm sure it is true. It will run with no error. But that doesn't mean I have understood the concept completely. :)

Comment: There's a slightly more detailed discussion in the preceding section, "Writing to a stream". If you understood that, you must understand this.

Comment: I'll revise that topic. Thanks for showing me that I might have not understood something completely,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator>>` have only 2 operands and return value, so when you write: `std::cin >> v1 >> v2` it means:

```
result = std::cin >> v1
result >> v2
```

here other example: `a + b + c` is

```
result = a + b
result + c
```

Comment: I think the addition example can be a bit confusing because `a + b` does not return `a`, so it's not exactly analoguous.

Comment: well, operator>> doesn't necessary returns the same stream - it depends how you overload it :)

Comment: Good point. It didn't cross my mind that's possible. I'm curious, do you know any practical uses for doing that?

Comment: I'm using operator<< for hashing, and operator returns new hash object: template <typename T>
Hasher operator<<(const Hasher& h, const T& v)
{
  return Hasher(calcHash(v, h.value));
}

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin >> v1` is an expression which will cause data to be read into `v1` and will evaluate to `std::cin`. Maybe it helps to visualise it like so:

```
(std::cin >> v1) >> v2;
//reads into v1 and evaluates to
(std::cin) >> v2; 
//equivalent to
std::cin >> v2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the first variant as the short-hand for the second. Similar to a + b + c being really (a + b) + c, meaning add a and b first, take the result of that and add c to it. So here, std::cin >> v1 returns a stream, we take that and operate the resulting stream with v2. You could optionally have ().